# c:set inside scriplet

Tags: jsp, jstl, scriptlet

Am reading `Cookies` and checking if a particular `Cookie` is found. If particular `Cookie` is found, am setting value into some variable and using it for further checks. Below is the code.

```
<%
        String showPacksCookie = "DisabledPackagesTab";
        Cookie[] cookielistTab = request.getCookies();

        if(cookielistTab != null)
          {
            for(int i = 0; i<cookielistTab.length; i++)
              {
                  Cookie cookie = cookielistTab[i];

                if(cookie.getName().contains(showPacksCookie) && cookie.getValue().equals("true"))
                {
                    <c:set var="showPackstab" value="display" scope="request" /> 
                  //Above is line 122
                    break;
                }
              }
        }
%>

<c:if test="${showPackstab eq 'display'}">
 <b>Tab</b><img src="/tabImage.gif" align="left" />
</c:if>
```

This code throws below exception,

`Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment` at line 122

Is it happening because am using JSTL inside Scriplet? How to get away with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scriptlets contain Java code. `<c:set>` is not valid Java code. What `<c:set>` does is

```
request.setAttribute("showPackstab", "display");
```

So this is the code you should have in your scriptlet.

But more importantly, you should not use scriptlets at all. Stick to the EL, the JSTL, and other custom tags. If the logic is too complex to be expressed using these, then it's a sign that it doesn't belong to the view (the JSP), but to the controller (a servlet or action written in Java, invoked before the JSP, which prepares the data for the JSP, and forwards to the JSP once the data is ready).

This is not the case here, since all of the above could be rewritten as:

```
<c:if test="${cookie.DisabledPackagesTab == 'true'}">
    <b>Tab</b><img src="/tabImage.gif" align="left" />
</c:if>
```

Comment: `request.setAttribute..` works perfectly. You suggested to stick to EL and gave the code also. But, scope of `cookie` is limited to `for` loop. Don't you think `${cookie.DisabledPackagesTab == 'true'}` doesn't work outside `Scriplet` ?

Comment: scriptlets contain Java code. Not JSP tags. Not JSP EL code. ${cookie.DisabledPackagesTab} means *"The value of the cookie named 'DisabledPackagesTab'"*. It doesn't need any scriptlet or for loop to work, because it will loop through the cookies for you, find the one which is named 'DisabledPackagesTab', and return its value.

Comment: You don't even need the `== 'true'` part there. EL will automatically coerce string to boolean.